# how to insert multiple data in multiple columns in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have form with one question and four choices, I am sending data into question table with

```
$this->db->insert('questions',$quest);
```

and choices in choices table with `$this->db->insert_batch('choices',$choices);` I am getting last insert id of question as `$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();` I want to send this id with each choice in question_no column in the choices table, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it right and `$choices` is an array.
Send both the arrays together from your controller. 
`$this->model_name->whatever($choices, $quest);`

then whatever function you have in model

```
 function whatever($choices, $quest){
     $this->db->insert('questions',$quest);

     $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

     $choices['quest_id'] = $last_id;

     $this->db->insert_batch('choices',$choices);

 }
```

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array' at line 1

INSERT INTO `choices` () VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), Array

Filename: C:/wamp/www/ci1/application/models/Model_questions.php

Line Number: 12

Comment: what is `var_dump($choices)` ?